# Powershell script that gets a list of users with contributor role from resource groups with specific tag

Tags: azure, powershell

I would like to write a script that gets all users having a role that contains "contributor" from resource groups with tag value "ApplicationName" with value that contains "..PROD.."

Users should not be replicated.

I tried first to get the list of RGs and list them but it doesnt work.

```
$outputFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\contributors.txt"

$resourceGroups = (Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags['applicationname'] -like "*PROD*" }).ResourceGroupName

foreach ($group in $resourceGroups) {
    Write-Host "Resource Group Name: $group"
    Write-Host "------------------------"
    $group | Out-File $outputFile
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question [output](https://i.imgur.com/kczi0AD.png)

Comment: Need confimation from op @olaf

Comment: @Imran Can you please share the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the users having a role that contains contributor from resource groups with tag value `ApplicationName` with value that contains `PROD` make use of below modified code:

```
$outputFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\contributors.txt"

# Get resource groups with the specified tag
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags -ne $null -and $_.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*PROD*" }

foreach ($group in $resourceGroups) {
    Write-Output "Resource Group Name: $($group.ResourceGroupName)"
    

    # Get role assignments for the resource group
    $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionName -like "*contributor*" -and $_.PrincipalType -eq "User" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SignInName -Unique

    foreach ($user in $roleAssignments) {
        Write-Output "User: $user"
        "$user" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile
    }  
}

Write-Output "Script execution completed."
```

***Output***:

```
Resource Group Name: rxxxx
Resource Group Name: imran
Resource Group Name: bolxx
Resource Group Name: test
Script execution completed.
```

To confirm in portal in my resource groups that contains contributor with tag value `ApplicationName` with value  `PROD`  like below:

[image]

### Update:

You can make use of below script to get the list of users with contributor role like below

```
# Get resource groups with the specified tag
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags -ne $null -and $_.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*PROD*" }
 
# Create an array to store the results
$results = @()
 
# Iterate through each resource group
foreach ($group in $resourceGroups) {
    $groupName = $group.ResourceGroupName
 
    # Get role assignments for the resource group
    $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $groupName | Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionName -like "*contributor*" -and $_.PrincipalType -eq "User" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SignInName -Unique
 
    foreach ($user in $roleAssignments) {
        $result = [ordered]@{
            'Resource Group Name' = $groupName
            'User' = $user
        }
        $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $result
    }  
 
    # Get all role assignments for the current resource group
    $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $groupName | Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionName -like "*contributor*" }
    # Iterate through each role assignment
    foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignments) {
        $result = [ordered]@{
            'Resource Group Name' = $groupName
            'Principal Name' = $roleAssignment.DisplayName
            'Role Name' = $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionName
        }
        $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $result
    } 
}
 
# Filter the results to only show the role assignments with the "Contributor" role
$results = $results | Where-Object { $_.'Role Name' -eq 'Contributor' }
 
# Output the results in a table format
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
 
# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\XXXXXX\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\host.csv" -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-Output "Script execution completed."
```

**Output**:

```
Resource Group Name Principal Name  Role Name  
------------------- --------------  ---------  

imran               imrankhan       Contributor
imran                User           Contributor
test                Venxxxxxx       Contributor
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Imran thank you, I tested the script but unfortunately I don't get the list of users on the file